# AWS DMS Task failed with error: Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-aurora, amazon-dms, citus

I want to migrate my PostgresDB hosted in Citus cloud service to AWS RDS Aurora Postgres. I am using AWS DMS service. Have created task but getting following errors:

Last failure message Last Error Stream Component Fatal error. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2860] [1020101] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_QOIS7XIGJDKNPY6RXMGYRLJQHY2P7IQBWIBA5NQ; Stream component 'st_0_QOIS7XIGJDKNPY6RXMGYRLJQHY2P7IQBWIBA5NQ' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2868] [1020101] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Frankly speaking not able to understand what is wrong here, so any help is appreciated.

cloudwatch logs:[image]

Comment: Have you considered contacting Amazon support?

Comment: no, as don't have an Amazon Tech support plan enabled on our account

Comment: @mustaccio is this issue/bug in AWS DMS itself?